# How to find the next record after a specified one in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to use a single SQL query (in MySQL) to find the record which comes after one that I specify.

I.e., if the table has:

```
id, fruit
--  -----
1   apples
2   pears
3   oranges
```

I'd like to be able to do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table where previous_record has id=1 order by id;
```

(clearly that's not real SQL syntax, I'm just using pseudo-SQL to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve)

which would return:

```
2, pears
```

My current solution is just to fetch all the records, and look through them in PHP, but that's slower than I'd like. Is there a quicker way to do it?

I'd be happy with something that returned two rows -- i.e. the one with the specified value and the following row.

EDIT: Sorry, my question was badly worded. Unfortunately, my definition of "next" is not based on ID, but on alphabetical order of fruit name. Hence, my example above is wrong, and should return oranges, as it comes alphabetically next after apples. Is there a way to do the comparison on strings instead of ids?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After the question's edit and the simplification below, we can change it to

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE fruit > 'apples' ORDER BY fruit LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Although in my version of MySQL, you have to put the "limit 1" outside the parens.

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that this does not quite do what I want. I'll edit the question to explain why.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I don't think that new version will work: e.g., if you apply it to oranges, won't it return apples instead of pears?

Comment: true... maybe fruit > 'apples' ORDER BY fruit LIMIT 1 will work, let me try

Comment: For previous entry: SELECT id FROM table WHERE fruit < 'apples' ORDER BY fruit DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Even simpler

UPDATE:

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE fruit > 'apples' ORDER BY fruit LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the MySQL syntax, but with SQL Server you can do something with "top", for example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY id;
```

This assumes that the id field is unique.  If it is not unique (say, a foreign key), you can do something similar and then join back against the same table.

Since I don't use MySQL, I am not sure of the syntax, but would imagine it to be similar.

Answer (score 2):

So simple, and no gymnastics required

```
Select * from Table
where id = 
    (Select Max(id) from Table
     where id < @Id)
```

or, based on the string @fruitName = 'apples', or 'oranges' etc...

```
Select * from Table
where id = 
    (Select Max(id) from Table
     where id < (Select id from Table
                 Where fruit = @fruitName))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify a sort order, I don't believe the concepts of "previous" or "next" are available to you in SQL.  You aren't guaranteed a particular order by the RDBMS by default.  If you can sort by some column into ascending or descending order that's another matter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know MySQL SQL but I still try

```
select n.id 
from   fruit n
,      fruit p
where  n.id = p.id + 1;
```

edit:

```
select n.id, n.fruitname 
from   fruits n
,      fruits p
where  n.id = p.id + 1;
```

edit two:

Jason Lepack has said that that doesn't work when there are gaps and that is true and I should read the question better.

I should have used analytics to sort the results on fruitname

```
select id
,      fruitname
,      lead(id) over (order by fruitname)  id_next
,      lead(fruitname) over (order by fruitname) fruitname_next
from   fruits;
```

Comment: This is assuming that there is no gap in the identity field.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  The string 'apples' will need to be a parameter.

Fill in that parameter with a string, and this query will return the entire record for the first fruit *after* that item, in alphabetical order.

Unlike the LIMIT 1 approach, this should be platform-independent.

```
--STEP THREE: Get the full record w/the ID we found in step 2
select *
from 
  fruits fr
 ,(   
  --STEP TWO: Get the ID # of the name we found in step 1
  select
    min(vendor_id) min_id
  from 
    fruits fr1
   ,(
    --STEP ONE: Get the next name after "apples"    
    select min(name) next_name
    from fruits frx
    where frx.name > 'apples'
    ) minval
  where fr1.name = minval.next_name
  ) x
where fr.vendor_id = x.min_id;
```

The equivalent to the LIMIT 1 approach in Oracle (just for reference) would be this:

```
select *
from
  (
  select *
  from fruits frx
  where frx.name > 'apples'
  order by name
  )
where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MS SQL Server 2008` (not sure if available for previous versions)...

In the event that you are trying to find the next record and you do not have a unique ID to reference in an applicable manner, try using `ROW_NUMBER().` See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Depending on how savvy your `T-SQL` skill is, you can create row numbers based on your sorting order.  Then you can find more than just the previous and next record.  Utilize it in views or sub-queries to find another record relative to the current record's row number.

Comment: The author said he's using MySQL, not MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cur.id as id, nxt.id as nextId, prev.id as prevId FROM video as cur
  LEFT JOIN video as nxt ON nxt.id > cur.id
  LEFT JOIN video as prev ON prev.id < cur.id
WHERE cur.id = 12
ORDER BY prev.id DESC, nxt.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

If you want the item with previous and next item this query lets you do just that.

This also allows You to have gaps in the data!

Answer (score -4):

How about this:

```
Select * from table where id = 1 + 1
```