# SQL select every Table1_ID where Table2.column 'x' occurs after 'Y'?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm quite new to SQL and having trouble stacking select arguments. 
 Select every StudyNumber whose table2.eventtype has a 'AcqOpened' occuring after (not directly after) a 'AssignedTo'.

```
 SELECT *
   FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Table1_ID
   WHERE Table2.eventtype ='AcqOpened' IN
        (
        SELECT Table1.ID
        FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Table1_ID
        WHERE Table2.eventtype > 'AssignedTo' ORDER BY Table1.ID, Table2.timestamp
        );
```

I've been putting variations on that into Access and getting back partial results and plenty of errors.  (I got the idea ">") from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402980/how-to-find-the-next-record-after-a-specified-one-in-sql):

Here is an example set for two Table1 entries and their corresponding Table2 entries.  For this set the desired output would be 4387 (or 00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml.) because 4387 has a AcqOpened after the AssignedTo.   (4386 does Not).

```
  Table1
ID      StudyNumber
---     ------------   
4386    00600137-A5BS13245-AT.xml
4387    00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml


  Table2
ID      Lookup_Studynumber(T1_ID)   eventtype       p1  p2  user    timestamp
--      -------------------------   -------------   --  --  -----   --------------------
27524   00600137-A5BS13245-AT.xml   AcqOpened               user    7/11/2014 8:28:35 AM
27525   00600137-A5BS13245-AT.xml   AcqModified             user    7/11/2014 8:30:40 AM
27526   00600137-A5BS13245-AT.xml   *AssignedTo*        -   user    7/11/2014 9:22:31 AM
27527   00600137-A5BS13245-AT.xml   AcqStateChange  -   -   user    7/11/2014 9:22:31 AM

27528   00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml   AcqOpened               user    7/14/2014 8:13:10 AM
27529   00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml   AcqModified             user    7/14/2014 8:16:34 AM
27530   00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml   *AssignedTo*        -   user    7/14/2014 10:26:40 AM
27531   00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml   AcqStateChange  -   -   user    7/14/2014 10:26:40 AM
27532   00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml   **AcqOpened**           user    7/18/2014 2:41:19 PM
27533   00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml   AcqModified             user    7/18/2014 2:41:21 PM
27534   00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml   AcqStateChange  -   -   user    7/18/2014 3:01:22 PM
27535   00600138-A5BS13245-AT.xml   AcqStateChange  -   -   user    12/19/2014 12:06:44 PM
```

If it helps these are auditevents logged per StudyNumber when anything is done with a dataset.   The eventtype is what action was taken.   The idea is to find which Table1 Id's (or StudyNumbers) are getting a second review.
When I imported them into Access it suggested I break it into two tables. 
Thank you very much for taking a look!!

Comment: An XML data set. I'm a human though. Can you share with us a sample of your two tables, and your desired output. It's difficult to understand from your description and xml output what you are trying to do.

Comment: How does this return anything? `'AcqOpened' > 'AssignedTo'` should always be false unless you are relying on vague enum evaluations.

Comment: Same as the previous comments. No XML please and the WHERE is incorrect. Maybe:  "WHERE Table2.eventtype ='AcqOpened' AND Table2.username = 'mkpsearl'  ?

Comment: And the title of the question describes nothing in the actual body of your post =/  at least nothing i can discern.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Sorry about the XML.  I had to import a large number of XML's to excel and excel to Access.      I'm going to to edit it with examples of the database.      Can you suggest a better title for the question?

Comment: IS this `Mysql` or `Access` Those are two very different databases.

Comment: Thanks.  Most of the questions I found helpful for the sql code were from Mysql answers so I thought they were similar.  Removing mysql tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply self-join query to extract the info from table2 based on the desired logic and then join table 1 with the results of previous sub-query.

```
select n.ID, n.StudyNumber 
from table1 n 
inner join
( select a.ID, a.[Lookup_Studynumber(T1_ID)] 
 from Table2 a 
 inner join Table2 b
 on a.[Lookup_Studynumber(T1_ID)]=b.[Lookup_Studynumber(T1_ID)] 
 and a.timestamp > b.timestamp --or apply appropriate logic
 where a.eventtype =  'AcqOpened'
 and b.eventtype = 'AssignedTo' ) s
 on n.Studynumber=s.[Lookup_Studynumber(T1_ID)]
 group by n.ID,n.StudyNumber
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Unfortunately it isn't returning any results as I'm entering it in.   Perhaps I'm not understanding it properly.  Am I supposed to be substituting n or a or b for anything?

Comment: Provide a better sample data and desired output.. In your current data sample table ID seems unique which means my script wont work.. if it is not unique then the sub-query I provided returns all those ID that have eventtype = assignedto and later acqopened. You don't have to substitute anything these are just aliases but you could run the subquery in isolation.

Comment: Ohhh...okay, now I see.  Yes. Table1 ID's and Table2 ID's are unique.  I'm modifying the example data with a (hopefully)less confusing set.

Comment: ok now that makes more sense.. Try to run my edited answer and let me know

Comment: It's working great!!!  I can't thank you enough!!   I've been puzzling over this for a long time. This is a HUGE help!!      (Now I understand Joins much better.  I wouldn't have ever thought to self-join a table.  Brilliant!)

Comment: Oh - I had to make one small tweak to the sub-select or it got confused:  ( select a.ID, a.[Lookup_Studynumber(T1_ID)]
 from

Comment: and yes you are right , forgot to add on the select even if i use the filed to join it with table1 later..

Comment: Accept the answer if you are happy in order for this question to be considered closed.